# Objective-C: bool incompatible pointer

Tags: objective-c, boolean

I am trying to figure out how to use bools in objective c. when i use them though they occasionally give a warning. Here is the code i have

```
NSString *userUserName = userNameTextField.text;
bool *userNameIsGood = false;
if (userNameTextField.text.length > 0){
    userNameIsGood = true;  // warning is only on this line
}
else {
    userNameIsGood = false;
}
```

the warning i get is: "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'bool *' from 'int'

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replace

```
bool *userNameIsGood = false;
```

to

```
bool userNameIsGood = false;
```

or

```
bool *userNameIsGood;

if (userNameTextField.text.length > 0){
    *userNameIsGood = true;  // warning is only on this line
}
else {
    *userNameIsGood = false;
}
```

Comment: @nfoggia Because `bool` is a native type, not a class.

Comment: you can use '*' if you need poiner to bool

Comment: Because in this case you need to use a variable not a pointer it. The * is used to indicate pointers to something, primitive types, or classes, or structures.A Pointer represents an address of memory. Is really important to have that clear. Take a deep breath and dig a little into C language.